# why does strchr() takes int type in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why does strchr take an int for the char to be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394011/why-does-strchr-take-an-int-for-the-char-to-be-found)

```
char *strchr(const char *string, int c);
```

why does strchr() takes int type in C ?
and how it works?

Comment: Quote from the manpage: `The strchr() function locates the first occurrence of c (converted to a char) in the string pointed to by s.` So it just casts the `int` down into a `char`, really.

Comment: answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2394011/1073981).