# Why `strchr` seems to work with multibyte characters, despite man page disclaimer?

Tags: c, string, utf-8, wchar-t

From:

```
man strchr
```

> char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
>
> The strchr() function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character c in the string s.
>
> Here "character" means "byte"; these functions do not work with wide or multibyte characters.

Still, if I try to search a multi-byte character like `é` (`0xC3A9` in UTF-8):

```
const char str[] = "This string contains é which is a multi-byte character";
char * pos = strchr(str, (int)'é');
printf("%s\n", pos);
printf("0x%X 0x%X\n", pos[-1], pos[0]);
```

I get the following output:

> � which is a multi-byte character
>
> 0xFFFFFFC3 0xFFFFFFA9

Despite the warning:

> warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

So here are my questions:

- What does it means `strchr` doesn't work with multi-byte characters ? (it **seems** to work, provided `int` type is big enough to contains your multi-byte that can be at most 4 bytes)
- How to get rid of the warning, i.e. how to safely recover the mult-byte value and store it in an int ?
- Why the prefixes `0xFFFFFF` ?

Comment: Why are you not using `wchar_t` here?

Comment: I chose to stick to UTF-8 chars everywhere in my code as `wchar_t` size is implementation defined: it can cause compatibility issues, and also because of [this](http://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: cast the char to unsigned first [Why does printf not print out just one byte when printing hex?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3555791/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strchr()` only seems to work for your multi-byte character.

The actual string in memory is

> ... c, o, n, t, a, i, n, s, ' ', 0xC3, 0xA9, ' ', w ...

When you call `strchr()`, you are really only searching for the `0xA9`, which are the lower 8 bits. That's why `pos[-1]` has the first byte of your multi-byte character: it was ignored during the search.

A `char` is signed on your system, which is why your characters are sign extended (the `0xFFFFFF`) when you print them out.

As for the warning, it seems that the compiler is trying to tell you that you are doing something odd, which you are. Don't ignore it.

Comment: Ok, I run the same code looking for `Ʃ` (0x01A9) and indeed, get the same result as if I searched for `é`.

Comment: Does using `strstr` looking for the string `"é"` (not the char `'é'`) is safe then (as `strstr` does not compares `\0`) ?

Answer (score 4):

That's the problem. It seems to work. Firstly, it's entirely up to the compiler what it puts in the string if you put multibyte characters in it, if indeed it compiles it at all. Clearly you are lucky (for some appropriate interpretation of lucky) in that it has filled your string with

```
.... c3, a9, ' ', 'w', etc
```

and that you are looking for `c3a9`, as it can find that fairly easily. The man page on strchr says:

> The  strchr()  function  returns  a  pointer  to  the  first occurrence  of  c  (converted  to a  char) in string s

So you pass c3a9 to this, which is converted to a `char` with value 'a9'. It finds the `a9` character, and you get returned a pointer to it.

The `ffffff` prefix is because you are outputting a signed character as a 32 bit hex number, so it sign extends it for you. This is as expected.

The problem is that 'undefined behaviour' is just that. It might work almost correctly. And it might not, depending on circumstances.

And again it is almost. You are not getting a pointer to the multibyte character, you are getting a pointer to the middle of it, (and I'm surprised you're interpreting that as working). If the multibyte character had evaluated to 0xff20 you'd get pointed to somewhere much earlier in the string.

Comment: I get it, thanks. Any idea why the API expects an `int` if it is then converted to `char` ?

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it is **implementation defined** what non-ASCII-7 characters (actually "non-basic-source-character-set characters"...) in the source get turned into by the compiler. If you want to play it safe and non-locale-dependent, you need to rely on `\x` or `\...` (octal). @Coconop: Passing characters around as `int` is common practice in the C API (because it leaves certain functions free to pass -1 for end-of-file).

Comment: @Coconop: It is converted to `unsigned char`. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394011/why-does-strchr-take-an-int-for-the-char-to-be-found) for an explanation.