# what's difference betwen int ch vs char ch

Tags: char, int, ch

why for in following function used `'t'` for `int ch`"?
ch is int, why use char?

Synopsis:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *strrchr(char *string, int c);
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char *s;
  char buf [] = "This is a testing";
  s = strrchr (buf, 't');
  if (s != NULL)
printf ("found a 't' at %s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does strchr take an int for the char to be found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394011/why-does-strchr-take-an-int-for-the-char-to-be-found)

Comment: oh jehy, i got my answer, thank you very much jehy,