# Creating a simplified version of strchr()

Tags: c

Trying to create a simple function that would look for a single char in a string "like strchr() would", i did the following:

```
char* findchar(char* str, char c)
{
    char* position = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == c)
        {
            position = &str[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return position;
}
```

So far it works. However, when i looked at the prototype of strchr():

```
char *strchr(const char *str, int c);
```

The second parameter is an int? I'm curious to know.. Why not a char? Does this mean that we can use int for storing characters just like we use a char?

Which brings me to the second question, i tried to change my function to accept an int as a second parameter... but i'm not sure if it's correct and safe to do the following:

```
char* findchar(char* str, int c)
{
    char* position = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == c) //Specifically, is this line correct? Can we test an int against a char? 
        {
            position = &str[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return position;
}
```

Comment: The second argument is an `int` for reasons of backwards compatibility between the old pre-standard code for `strchr()` and the C89/C90 standard version.  The standard says: _The `strchr` function locates the first occurrence of `c` (converted to a `char`) in the
string pointed to by `s`._. When searching for equality, it doesn't matter much whether it is converted to plain `char` (which may be signed or unsigned) or it is converted to `unsigned char`; the rules for `strcmp()` are different — it interprets the values as `unsigned char` because it must order them correctly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your reply, if i have understood correctly, the second int parameter in strchr() gets converted to char before actually looking for an occurence?

Comment: That's what the standard says.  It means that if you pass a value outside the range `CHAR_MIN .. CHAR_MAX`, then the value is truncated to a `char`.  Then the comparison expression inside the function converts both the element of the string and the `char` back to `int` again because that always happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the return value of `fgetc()`, values in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`, some negative value.  This is the kind of value to pass to `strchr()`.

[@Roland Illig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42019620/2410359) presents a very good explanation of the history that led to retaining use of `int ch` with `strchr()`.

---

OP's code fails/has trouble as follows.

1) `char* str` is treated like `unsigned char *str` per §7.23.1.1 3

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type unsigned char

2) `i` should be type `size_t`, to handle the entire range of the character array.

3) For the purpose of `strchr()`, the *null character* is considered part of the search.

> The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string.

4) Better to use `const` as `str` is not changed.

```
char* findchar(const char* str, int c)     {
    const char* position = NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    for(i = 0; ;i++) {
        if((unsigned char) str[i] == c) {
            position = &str[i];
            break;
        }
        if (str[i]=='\0') break;
    }
    return (char *) position;
}
```

---

Further detail

> The `strchr` function locates the ﬁrst occurrence of `c` (converted to a `char`) in the string pointed to by `s`. C11dr §7.23.5.2  2

So `int c` is treat like a `char`.  This could imply

```
        if((unsigned char) str[i] == (char) c) {
```

Yet what I think this is meant:

```
        if((unsigned char) str[i] == (unsigned char)(char) c) {
```

or simply

```
        if((unsigned char) str[i] == (unsigned char)c) {
```

Comment: @user7427260 In the end makes little difference.   I used `const char* position` to match `const char* str ...position = &str[i];` and `return (char *) position;` to match the return type of  `char *strchr(const char *s, int c);`.  It is a compromise of `strchr()` accepting `char *` and `const char *`.  rectified in C++.

Comment: thank you very much! so i need to cast to make sure that the test condition is done correctly.. thanks again!

Comment: It would generally be simpler (and equally or more efficient) not to have the `i` variable at all, but instead just to rewrite the loop to increment the `position` pointer directly, as in: `for (position = str; *position != '\0'; position++) { if (*position == c) return position; }`. Of course, depending on the type of `i` and other details, a good optimizing compiler *might* be able to recognize that these functions do effectively the same thing, and compile them into the same optimized assembly code.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Agreed.  A re-write would likely result in better flowing code.  Yet that much might lose instructive connection to OP's original code. Unfortunately your suggestion of `for (position = str; *position != '\0'; position++) ...` returns `NULL` when `ch == 0`.  Code  should return the end of the string address: functionality before performance.

Comment: @chux Good point about the `c == '\0'` case, although one way to handle that would be to add the line `if (c == '\0') return position;` after the loop (and before the final `return NULL;`).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen This answer's code is not very tight.  An example tight solution would be `char* strchr(const char* str, int c) {
  do {
    if ((unsigned char) *str == (unsigned char) c) {
      return (char *) str;
    }
  } while (*str);
  return NULL;
}`

Comment: @chux I forgot to ask you about this: `char* str` is treated like `unsigned char *str`? Why is that? I'm just sticking to ASCII so plain char should be fine?

Comment: @user7427260 "I'm just sticking to ASCII" --> does that include everyone who might use or refer to your fine code from now on?  If so. yes - no problem.  Yet why write code with that limitation when portability is just a small step away?

Comment: @chux so if i have understood correctly it's done for compatibility with eight-bit character encodings like Extended ASCII?

Answer (score 7):

Before ANSI C89, functions were declared without prototypes. The declaration for `strchr` looked like this back then:

```
char *strchr();
```

That's it. No parameters are declared at all. Instead, there were these simple rules:

- all pointers are passed as parameters as-is
- all integer values of a smaller range than `int` are converted to `int`
- all floating point values are converted to `double`

So when you called `strchr`, what really happened was:

```
strchr(str, (int)chr);
```

When ANSI C89 was introduced, it had to maintain backwards compatibility. Therefore it defined the prototype of `strchr` as:

```
char *strchr(const char *str, int chr);
```

This preserves the exact behavior of the above sample call, including the conversion to `int`. This is important since an implementation may define that passing a `char` argument works differently than passing an `int` argument, which makes sense on 8 bit platforms.

Comment: Do you have any source for this? It is not mentioned in the C rationale.

Comment: On the contrary, 3.7.1 of the C rationale seems to says the opposite of what you claim here.

Comment: AFAIK, prototypes were already included in the second edition of the K&R book.

Comment: @EOF: Yes, 2nd Edition of K&R includes prototypes and was based originally on the draft standard (and largely checked using C++ compilers).  There was quite a long pause between most of the standard being ready and the final version.  There were interesting politics involved, related to internationalization (aka I18N), and functions like `localeconv()` were part of that (trigraphs too, IIRC).  So, the majority of standard C was known for a year or two (or more) before the standard was published.

Comment: @Lundin The rationale for ISO C99 gives some reasons in 6.5.2.2, though `strchr` is not mentioned there because it doesn't differ from all the other affected functions.

Comment: @RolandIllig Actually 6.5.2.2 doesn't say much but I now noticed that it points to 7.1.4: "All library prototypes are specified in terms of the “widened” types: an argument formerly declared as char is now written as int. This ensures that most library functions can be called with or without a prototype in scope, thus maintaining backwards compatibility with pre-C89 code."

Comment: However, there are still plenty of separate rationales stating the EOF case too.