# Why int exists in C, Why not just short and long

Tags: c, ansi-c

A `short` is at least 16 bits and a `long` is at least 32 bits, so what's the point of an `int` which can be either 16-bit or 32-bit?

PS: I'm talking about ANSI C here.

Comment: `int` is (in most cases, this isn't possible for 8bit architectures) the *natural word size* of the machine, and therefore often the most performant. On IA32, integer arithmetics in 32 bit indeed can perform better than in 16bit.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, thank's, so it's preferable to use `int` even if you need only, say 8 bits variable, (in arithmetic calculations for example).

Comment: it depends. Maybe size is your bigger concern? But, as a rule of thumb, and apart from size-constrained systems: Use `int` whenever you need an integer of at least 16bit, but don't care about the actual bigger size.

Comment: @Bite Bytes values smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` for arithmetic calculations anyway (so that intermediate steps do not so easily overflow) so you may be giving the machine *more* work to do, not less.

Comment: @WeatherVane is this a part of the standard?

Comment: Please see [section 6.3 here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and footnote 48.

Comment: ...because it's like porridge.  If it's too hot, or too cold, it's not so useful.

Comment: by the way, the standard doesn't say `int` can only be 16 or 32 bits, only that `int` is at least 16 bits (and not larger than `long`)

Comment: in the past the only type is int. There were not even `char` or `void`

Comment: That's why [`memset` takes an `int` instead of a `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5919735/995714). [The same to `strchr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2394011/995714)

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @UnholySheep from K&R second edition I quote: 
**_"int will normally be the natural size for a particular machine. short is often 16 bits, long 32 bits, and int either 16 or 32 bits."_**

Comment: 1. *"Normally"* does not mean that no other sizes are allowed, it's just that these two are the most common. 2. K&R is _not_ the standard

Comment: @BiteBytes there are lots of architectures with [18-bit int, 24-bit int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6971886/995714), [36-bit int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2098149/995714) or even [60-bit int](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29)

Answer (score 3):

`short`, `int` and `long` are by definition three different Type specifiers, where, `short int` ranks lower than `int` which ranks lower than `long int`.

C standard only specifies the *minimum* (*and comparative, for example, `int` cannot be wider than `long`*) requirements, an implementation may choose to provide any other *wider* definition of the types, keeping the constraints alive.